# Groovy script to convert text file into table

Tags: groovy

I have a pipe(|) delimited text file with header and I have to convert this file into table format using Groovy script. I am passing this file through a variable. I need to send this table in a  mailbody of notification mail without attachment.

The sample source file is given below.

Please help..

```
AttachmentName|CreationDateTime|ID|MailBox|Processed|Subject
1279_001.pdf|20180411 121519.761||scanning_4WH@suzuki.be|N|FW: TNT Belgium - 020202
1296_001.pdf|20180411 121519.793||scanning_4WH@suzuki.be|N|FW: Wedig truck of yesterday
```

Regards
Jay

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
list_of_list = new File('test.txt').readLines().collect{ it.tokenize('|')}
```

So you can get as list of list here. Use **j-text-util** for pretty printing as table.